# How does chef resolve core resources?

Tags: chef-infra

Using chef-apply, It seems to me that [this line](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/application/apply.rb#L192) is what triggers resource resolution and adds it to the resource collection of the run_context.

I have tried to dive into and follow where the code goes but I cannot find where it resolves a resource and then adds the instance of the resource to resource collection.

Where does chef add the resource into the run_context?

Comment: What are you trying to more specifically? The internals of the DSL are both very complex and intentionally undocumented :) you can find most of the details under the chef/dsl folder, with the core method being define_resource.

Comment: @coderanger  sorry for the late reply. I am curious to know where and how resources get "wired" into the Chef::Recipe object. My understanding is that because instance_eval is called with the recipe text, resources such as "execute" etc are also somehow an instance method of the Chef::Recipe object.

Comment: Via a complex set of mixin, yes. As I said above, this is considered an implementation detail and not something to depend on. The precise details have changed many times over the years.